# How to calculate residues? $f(z)=h-\cos{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know how to calculate the residues of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$.

**My attempts**: I first calculated zeros of $f(z)$, and I got
$$\exp{iz}=h+\sqrt{h^2-1}$$
and then
$$z=-i\log{(h+\sqrt{h^2-1})}$$
and here I got stuck.

I'm really confused, how can I compute residues with this $z$? And is my solution correct?

I don't even know which one is better, $\pm \sqrt{h^2-1}$ or just $+\sqrt{h^2-1}$?
I think this root symbol means complex roots so I don't think I need $\pm$ because $\sqrt{h^2-1}$ itself has two roots of $h^2-1$.

My questions are: **How can I compute residues with that complicated reros?** and **Which is better, $+$ or $\pm$?**

Answer (score 1):

No, the $\sqrt{w}$ symbol denotes a function value, that is one of the roots. Usually the one with smallest (if in doubt positive) phase/angle/argument.

The equation $e^{iz}=w$ has infinitely many solutions
$$
iz=\operatorname{Ln}(w)+i2\pi\Bbb Z
$$
so that you get solutions
$$
z=\pm i\operatorname{Ln}(h+\sqrt{h^2-1})+2\pi\Bbb Z.
$$
using $h-\sqrt{h^2-1}=(h+\sqrt{h^2-1})^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P:=\{\pm i\operatorname{Ln}(h+\sqrt{h^2-1})+2\pi k: k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Then $\cos z=h \iff z \in P$ (see the answer of LutzL) and each $z \in P$ is a simple pole of $1/f$. Hence, for $w \in P$:

$Res(1/f;w)= \lim_{z \to w} \frac{z-w}{f(z)}$.

Your turn !

Comment: I guess I can use l'Hopitale's rule and the answer is $-\frac{1}{\sin{w}}=\sqrt{1-h^2}$ Correct?